# The sum function returns answers different from an explicit loop

Tags: fortran

I am converting f77 code to f90 code, and part of the code needs to sum over elements of a 3d matrix. In f77 this was accomplished by using 3 loops (over outer,middle,inner indices). I decided to use the f90 intrinsic sum (3 times) to accomplish this, and much to my surprise the answers differ. I am using the ifort compiler, have debugging, check-bounds, no optimization all turned on

Here is the f77-style code

```
r1 = 0.0
do k=1,nz
  do j=1,ny
    do i=1,nx
      r1 = r1 + foo(i,j,k)
    end do
  end do
end do
```

and here is the f90 code

```
r = SUM(SUM(SUM(foo, DIM=3), DIM=2), DIM=1)
```

I have tried all sorts of variations, such as swapping the order of the loops for the f77 code, or creating temporary 2D matrices and 1D arrays to "reduce" the dimensions while using SUM, but the explicit f77 style loops always give different answers from the f90+ SUM function.

I'd appreciate any suggestions that help understand the discrepancy.

By the way this is using one serial processor.

Edited 12:13 pm to show complete example

```
! ifort -check bounds -extend-source 132 -g -traceback -debug inline-debug-info -mkl -o verify  verify.f90
! ./verify

program verify

implicit none

integer :: nx,ny,nz

parameter(nx=131,ny=131,nz=131)

integer :: i,j,k
real :: foo(nx,ny,nz)
real :: r0,r1,r2
real :: s0,s1,s2
real :: r2Dfooxy(nx,ny),r1Dfoox(nx)

call random_seed
call random_number(foo)

r0 = 0.0
do k=1,nz
  do j=1,ny
    do i=1,nx
      r0 = r0 + foo(i,j,k)
    end do
  end do
end do

r1 = 0.0
do i=1,nx
  do j=1,ny
    do k=1,nz
      r1 = r1 + foo(i,j,k)
    end do
  end do
end do

r2 = 0.0
do j=1,ny
  do i=1,nx
    do k=1,nz
      r2 = r2 + foo(i,j,k)
    end do
  end do
end do

!*************************

s0 = 0.0
s0 = SUM(SUM(SUM(foo, DIM=3), DIM=2), DIM=1)

s1 = 0.0
r2Dfooxy = SUM(foo,   DIM = 3)
r1Dfoox  = SUM(r2Dfooxy, DIM = 2)
s1 = SUM(r1Dfoox)

s2 = SUM(foo)

!*************************

print *,'nx,ny,nz = ',nx,ny,nz
print *,'size(foo) = ',size(foo)

write(*,'(A,4(ES15.8))') 'r0,r1,r2          = ',r0,r1,r2
write(*,'(A,3(ES15.8))') 'r0-r1,r0-r2,r1-r2 = ',r0-r1,r0-r2,r1-r2

write(*,'(A,4(ES15.8))') 's0,s1,s2          = ',s0,s1,s2
write(*,'(A,3(ES15.8))') 's0-s1,s0-s2,s1-s2 = ',s0-s1,s0-s2,s1-s2

write(*,'(A,3(ES15.8))') 'r0-s1,r1-s1,r2-s1    = ',r0-s1,r1-s1,r2-s1

stop
end

!**********************************************
```

```
sample output

nx,ny,nz =          131         131         131
size(foo) =      2248091

r0,r1,r2          =  1.12398225E+06 1.12399525E+06 1.12397238E+06
r0-r1,r0-r2,r1-r2 = -1.30000000E+01 9.87500000E+00 2.28750000E+01
s0,s1,s2          =  1.12397975E+06 1.12397975E+06 1.12398225E+06
s0-s1,s0-s2,s1-s2 =  0.00000000E+00-2.50000000E+00-2.50000000E+00
r0-s1,r1-s1,r2-s1    =  2.50000000E+00 1.55000000E+01-7.37500000E+00
```

Comment: What kind of problems do you face, and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Why using nested `sum` and not just one `sum` command

Comment: Just to clarify albert's comment r = Sum( foo ) is enough. But at the very least you need to tell us what the different answers are, and exactly what dimensions foo has - are you sure you aren't summing over uninitialized data?

Comment: This is basically a 3D integral. So a simple sum over the various elements gives me the answer (without going into the intricacies of eg trapezoidal integration etc) This it is not reassuring to see different answers.

I have edited the original message to show a complete minimal verifiable example. You will see various incarnations of the loops, and of calling sum. The top line shows how I compiled.

A few give the same results, others give different results.

Comment: Look a bit like a numerical problem (the number of significant  digits, it is well known that (a+b)+c is not equal to a+(b+c) on a computer). What happens when you use double precision instead of real?

Comment: Agreed with @albert, You are adding up over 2 million numbers in single precision which only has about 6-7 digits of precision.

Answer (score 0):

First, welcome to StackOverflow. [Please take the tour!](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) There is a reason we expect a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because we look at your code and can only guess at what might be the case and that is not too helpful for the community.

I hope the following suggestions helps you figure out what is going on.

Use the size() function and print what Fortran thinks are the sizes of the dimensions as well as printing nx, ny, and nz. As far as we know, the array is declared bigger than nx, ny, and nz and these variables are set according to the data set. Fortran does not necessarily initialize arrays to zero depending on whether it is a static or allocatable array.

You can also try specifying array extents in the sum function:

```
r = Sum(foo(1:nx,1:ny,1:nz))
```

If done like this, at least we know that the sum function is working on the exact same slice of foo that the loops loop over.

If this is the case, you will get the wrong answer even though there is nothing 'wrong' with the code. This is why it is particularly important to give that [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://[Minimal,%20Complete,%20and%20Verifiable%20example])

Comment: Thanks Dan and Vladimir for your suggestions. I have edited my original post to show you examples of the code giving different results. In the posted code I initialize foo using a random generator, in the actual code I am writing, it will be initialized to sine waves in a fluid (which will eventaully become turbulent)

Comment: The use of the slice notation may cause the compiler to generate a temporary.  It is better to simply do `r = sum(foo)`.

Comment: OK thanks everyone for helpful points and suggestions. Lessons learned are sum(foo) may be more accurate than the looped addition, because "sum" may be optimized to take into account the magnitudes of the individual elements of the array; plus double precision would be better than real.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the differences now. These are typical rounding errors from adding small numbers to a large sum. The processor is allowed to use any order of the summation it wants. There is **no "right" order**. You can**not** really say that the original loops make the "correct" answer and the others do not.

What you can do is to use **double precision**. In extreme circumstances there are tricks like the Kahan summation but one rarely needs that.

Addition of a small number to a large sum is imprecise and especially so in single precision. You still have four significant digits in your result.

---

One typically does not use the `DIM=` argument, that is used in certain special circumstances.

If you want to sum all elements of `foo`, use just

```
s0 = SUM(foo)
```

That is enough.

What

```
s0 = SUM(SUM(SUM(foo, DIM=3), DIM=2), DIM=1)
```

does is that it will make a temporary 2D arrays with each element be the sum of the respective row in the z dimension, then a 1D array with each element the sum over the last dimension of the 2D array and then finally the sum of that 1D array. If it is done well, the final result will be the same, but it well eat a lot of CPU cycles.

Comment: OK from the replies I am getting, sounds like
a) the do loops are the most accurate as "sum" is a processor dependant approximation .. so for my purposes the do loops would be best
b) I tried the "double precision" suggestion, and yes the comparisons came out much better in all cases

Comment: On the contrary, @SergioSM, `sum` is potentially _more_ accurate.  I wouldn't expect it to be worse than following the explicit order of a do loop (compiler can reorder in some cases).

Comment: Given that summing in different orders can give different results it is very difficult to say what the most accurate result is. And Sum might actually use tricks like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm behind the scenes - I have talked to compiler developers who were definitely considering this.

Answer (score 0):

The `sum` intrinsic function returns a processor-dependant approximation to the sum of the elements of the array argument.  This is not the same thing as adding sequentially all elements.

It is simple to find an array `x` where

```
summation = x(1) + x(2) + x(3)
```

(performed strictly left to right) is not the best approximation for the sum treating the values as "mathematical reals" rather than floating point numbers.

---

As a concrete example to look at the nature of the approximation with ifort, we can look at the following program.  We need to enable optimizations here to see effects; the importance of *order of summation* is apparent even with optimizations disabled (with `-O0` or `-debug`).

```
  implicit none

  integer i
  real x(50)
  real total

  x = [1.,(EPSILON(0.)/2, i=1, SIZE(x)-1)]
  total = 0
  do i=1, SIZE(x)
     total = total+x(i)
     print '(4F17.14)', total, SUM(x(:i)), SUM(DBLE(x(:i))), REAL(SUM(DBLE(x(:i))))
  end do
end program
```

If adding up in strict order we get `1.`, seeing that anything smaller in magnitude than `epsilon(0.)` doesn't affect the sum.

You can experiment with the size of the array and order of its elements, the scaling of the small numbers and the ifort floating point compilation options (such as `-fp-model strict`, `-mieee-fp`, `-pc32`).  You can also try to find an example like the above using double precision instead of default real.

Comment: As shown by the fact that r0 and s2 have the same value.